# Error installing Python 3 with Homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew, macos-sierra

I'm having trouble when I want to install Python 3 using Homebrew.

This is my console:

```
$ brew install python3
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
==> Installing dependencies for python3: readline, sqlite, gdbm, makedepend, openssl
==> Installing python3 dependency: readline
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-6.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/slorenzo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/readline-6.3.8.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2af/raw/746fc543e56bc37

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "readline--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2af/raw/746fc543e56bc37a26ccf05d2946a45176b0894e/readline-6.3.8.diff
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running:

> If Homebrew was updated on Aug 10-11th 2016 and `brew update` always says `Already up-to-date` you need to run:

```
cd "$(brew --repo)" && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master && brew update
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of Homebrew. [The patch file that's failing to download was removed from the recipe in September 2016](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/dc88c4b2a2fce52b4c69e9b1d60a7692c2b7eadf), and the warning about macOS 10.12 being a "pre-release version" is clearly no longer correct.

Run `brew update` and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but the console says: `Already up-to-date.`